# PHP framework to build Workflow Management system

Tags: php, frameworks, workflow

I am looking for PHP framework to build a Workflow Management system. 
While searching on net i got RADICORE which is quite best one. Just looking for more option so that I can compare them and go with one of them

My requirement is as:
I need framework that can define a workflow as we do in RADICORE and then play around it. 
Playing means that if there 4 steps in my workflow, i can drop one and see How the workflow proceeds. 
There are many frameworks through which you can generate a graph of your existing flow.
So i am basically interested in defining a workflow rather than generating the graph for existing framework.

And i should be an open source framework (basically PHP).

Comment: I am advising Zend Framework to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248393/workflow-tools-comparison

Comment: Well looking for a product/framework similar to RADICORE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Zeta/ezComponents has a Workflow engine.](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Workflow). It's OpenSource and free to use. No clue how that compares to other engines though.

Comment: hasn't been maintained for over 3 years

Comment: @shorif2000 question is offtopic anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest [formapro/pvm](https://github.com/formapro/pvm) library.

The library provides us with a frame to build a [workflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow) or business processes such as [BPMN](http://www.bpmn.org/). 
It works like this: you build a process, create nodes and transitions, link them up. Then you can do:

- Save process and execute later.
- Clone and execute several processes.
- Pause & continue execution.
- Supports async transition. Execute tasks in parallel.
- Supports fork-join, conditions, cycles and so on.

It is backed up by [workflow nets (WF-nets)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) and [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) theories. . Here's a good [post on how Petri Nets works](https://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~mchen/BioPNML/Intro/pnfaq.html)

It's very powerful and at the same easy to use (thanks to Petri Nets theory).